# How to set up User email verification after Signup?

Tags: users, email, user-registration, email-verification

You know how all these websites send out links to their new users for them to verify their Email address? I'm trying to set up something like this but after some research I still haven't found a good explanation on how to implement this.

I'm open for plugin recommendations, however most of the plugins I found have a ton of other features that I don't really need.

Without using a plugin, how would I go about adding this to my code?

My approach would be to add a 'Email not verified' attribute to the user meta after signup and send out an email with some kind of verification key to the user. How can I verify if the user actually clicked on that link though?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `user_register` hook

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_registration', 10, 2 );
function my_registration( $user_id ) {
    // get user data
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    // create md5 code to verify later
    $code = md5(time());
    // make it into a code to send it to user via email
    $string = array('id'=>$user_id, 'code'=>$code);
    // create the activation code and activation status
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'account_activated', 0);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'activation_code', $code);
    // create the url
    $url = get_site_url(). '/my-account/?act=' .base64_encode( serialize($string));
    // basically we will edit here to make this nicer
    $html = 'Please click the following links <br/><br/> <a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
    // send an email out to user
    wp_mail( $user_info->user_email, __('Email Subject','text-domain') , $html);
}
```

You can check for `$_GET['act']` and then activate if that's a valid key by updating the meta value `account_activated`. You can use `wp_authenticate_user` hook to verify activation status every time when user tries to login.

Snippet to validate:

```
add_action( 'init', 'verify_user_code' );
function verify_user_code(){
    if(isset($_GET['act'])){
        $data = unserialize(base64_decode($_GET['act']));
        $code = get_user_meta($data['id'], 'activation_code', true);
        // verify whether the code given is the same as ours
        if($code == $data['code']){
            // update the user meta
            update_user_meta($data['id'], 'is_activated', 1);
            wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Success:</strong> Your account has been activated! ', 'text-domain' )  );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful! One thing though, how can I access the User ID and the $code from the url? I surely need to decode it somehow?

Comment: I updated the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Guys I think the above method introduces security vulnerabilities that do not need to be there.

The primary goal of email verification is that we want people who signup to provide a real email address that they own or at least have access to. We do not want people signing up with lets say a random email address that someone else owns, for instance your email address.

The above code has vulnerabilities that could enable a hacker to register a random email address someone else owns and then relevantly easily brute force the $user_id value and the $code value on your email verification page.

**1st vulnerability**

You are using $user_id. Now I know this value could be any number of things but typically this is going to be an integer especially if using wordpress which is circa 30% of the websites on the internet and looking at the above php code it is indeed based on wordpress. The hacker is either given their $user_id as part of the signup process or else they guess their $user_id via brute force just going up sequentially starting at the number 1 and continuing 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6 ..... they will guess their $user_id in less than a day perhaps in even in less than an hour if your website does not have that many members.

**2nd vulnerability**

You are creating a $code using the MD5 hashing function and the time of signup. The hacker knows what time they signed up. Let's say the hacker signs-up at 3pm. Now all the hacker has to do is MD5 hash times from 2.55pm to 3.05pm and they will brute force the $code in less than an hour.

**Looking at the above the hacker can just brute force the $user_id and $code in less than a day and verify an email address that they do not own**

tut tut tut

A better approach would be to generate a $code with the rand() function using uppercase (A-Z) and lower case (a-z), numbers (0-9) and special characters e.g. (!&#).  That MD5 hashing function is only using numbers 0-9 and lower case letters a-f and they way ye are using it based on the time of signup is making it incredibly easy to narrow down and brute force attack.

I have written the below PHP code the generate a random $code with Uppercase Letters/Lowercase Letters/Intergers/Special Characters. Don't make it so easy for hackers guys.

```php
function generateRandomString($stringLength){
    //specify characters to be used in generating random string, do not specify any characters that wordpress does not allow in the creation.
    $characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_[]{}!@$%^*().,>=-;|:?";

    //get the total length of specified characters to be used in generating random string
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);

    //declare a string that we will use to create the random string 
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $stringLength; $i++) {
        //generate random characters
        $randomCharacter = $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        //add the random characters to the random string
        $randomString .=  $randomCharacter;
    };

    //sanitize_user, just in case 
    $sanRandomString = sanitize_user($randomString);

    //check that random string contains Uppercase/Lowercase/Intergers/Special Char and that it is the correct length
    if ( (preg_match('([a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-zA-Z].*[_\W])', $sanRandomString)==1) && (strlen($sanRandomString)==$stringLength) )
    {
        //return the random string if it meets the complexity criteria 
        return $sanRandomString;
    } else {
        // if the random string does not meet minimium criteria call function again 
        return call_user_func("generateRandomString",($stringLength) );
    }
}//end of generateRandomString function

//call the function to generate a random string with Uppercase Letters/Lowercase Letters/Intergers/Special Characters 
//into the function we pass the length of string we require, in this exampe it will generate a string 32 characters long
$code = generateRandomString(32);

echo $code;
```

Comment: Great answer! It would be even a little better if you formatted the code a bit. Additionally the $ needs to be escaped. Also, correct me if I'm wrong but there's no reason to use `call_user_func` over calling the function directly.

Comment: The reason i am using call_user_function is the function is creating a random string to whatever length you specify. In the event that the random string complexity criteria is not met the function will just execute again automatically, for instance if the function generated a random string that did not contain an upper case letter or a number then call_user_function executes the function again. The function will only return a random string once it meets all the complexity criteria.

Comment: I have tested using  base_64_encode on the $code generated by the random string function attach to $url then retrieve with GET method without issue.

Comment: Also very bad idea just to send the $code directly to the get_user_meta as this is same like storing plain text password in a database. You should be encrypting the $code stored in get_user_meta. Then de-crypt using the $code attached to the $url. Otherwise you just bypassed the whole point of wordpress security password hashing. Look at your wp-users, no passwords are stored in plain text, so you also need to hash   the password reset $code before storing. Use function password_hash() to encrypyt and password_verify()  to decrypt

Comment: I don't think that a user activation code necessarily needs to be hashed to be secure. If someone accesses your database, the user activation codes really don't matter, they can just set the email to confirmed, though they probably have a lot worse in mind. Regarding `call_user_function`, I'm still not understanding why you can't just call the function from itself. Can a function not call itself in PHP?

Comment: Yes the function is called directly in the above code at the end where it says "$code = generateRandomString(32);". There function is using preg match to check if the generated random string has Uppercase Letters/Lowercase Letters/Intergers/Special Characters. If the random string does not met the complexity criteria call_user_function automatically executes the function again. The function will keep generating random strings until one of them meets the complexity criteria specified in the preg match. The first random string could be "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef"

Comment: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef" does not met the complexity requirements as it has no numbers, upper case letters or special characters so call_user_function automatically recalls the function until we get a random string that meets the complexity requirements. It is acting like a loop.

Comment: I'm curious as to why if wordpress is hashing the account password in the database that you would not also hash the reset key for that very password also?

Comment: Do you think wordpress should not be hashing account passwords in the database ?

Comment: @MikeMoy I just came across your answer and I would really like to use your code if that's ok. Would I use it together with the first 2 actions in the first answer, or would it be replacing any of the code from the first answer?